# web2py - How do I insert html with {{block ...}} in it into another html?

Tags: html, web2py, web2py-modules

view1.html:

```
{{block left_sidebar}}
asdf
{{end}}
```

debug.html:

```
{{left_sidebar_enabled = True}}
{{extend 'layout.html'}}
{{include 'view1.html'}}
```

controller:

```
def debug():
    return {}
```

The content from view1.html doesn't appear and I don't understand why.

If I modify view1.html as follows:

```
{{block left_sidebar}}
asdf
{{end}}
qwer
```

`qwer` does appear on the page but not `asdf`.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blocks go in extending views, not in included views (i.e., an extending view can define a block that also exists in the view it extends, and the block in the extending view will replace the block in the extended view). So:

```
{{block left_sidebar}}
asdf
{{end}}
```

would go in debug.html (not in view.html), in which case it will replace the `left_sidebar` block in layout.html.